# Tigervnc error - unable to connect to socket: Connection refused (61)

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, raspberry-pi, vnc

I am using a Mac and I have Raspian running on a Raspberry Pi 4. I'm also a complete beginner and everything is just so confusing. I am on a headless setup. I connected to the raspberry pi using SSH on my Mac terminal app.

I installed tigervnc-standalone-server on the raspberry pi and tigervnc-viewer on my Mac. I logged onto the raspberry pi from the Mac terminal with the following command:

```
ssh myusername@192.168.1.9 -L 9901:localhost:5901
```

Then started vncserver:

```
vncserver -geometry 1400x900
```

And the server is running fine. Then in a new terminal window when I try to connect to it using the command:

```
vncviewer localhost:5901
```

It doesn't connect and says unable to connect to socket: Connection refused (61)

I turned off my firewall on my Mac in the settings app but still the same issue...

EDIT: I have tried using `sudo netstat -tulpn` to see what's listening what port and these are the results:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      499/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      387/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      476/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1684/Xtigervnc      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1429/ssh            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      499/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      387/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      476/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN      1684/Xtigervnc      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9901                :::*                    LISTEN      1429/ssh            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58935           0.0.0.0:*                           362/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           422/dhcpcd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           438/cups-browsed    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           362/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::51062                :::*                                362/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::546                  :::*                                422/dhcpcd          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                362/avahi-daemon: r
```

EDIT2: I tried using another method. I installed vncviewer on my Mac. I also removed tigervnc-standalone-server and installed realvnc-vnc-server on the raspberry pi. I opened the vncviewer application and started a new connection. It asked for my raspberry pi username and password and it connected!

[image: connecting via vncviewer]

So just wondering what is the difference and why won't the SSH tunnelling work.

EDIT3: Instead of

```
ssh myusername@192.168.1.9 -L 9901:localhost:5901
```

I entered:

```
ssh myusername@192.168.1.9 -L 5901:localhost:5901
```

Comment: So you opened a reverse SSH tunnel to the Pi and are trying to connect VNC through that tunnel. Is the VNC server listening on port 9901? Maybe [this TechRepublic article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-vnc-using-ssh/) would help resolve the issue?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes I followed pretty much the same thing as the article. How can I check if the VNC server is listening on the port 9901?

Comment: I'd double-check, as the way presented in the article should work, whereas "pretty much same" might omit some small but important detail. By default VNC isn't listening on that port, it's listening on 590x. To check what's listening which port, `sudo netstat -tulpn`. Pls note that the article refers to a situation when VNC default port isn't allowed in the network. If this is your private network and everything's running on defaults, you don't need SSH, the client can connect just with the server's IP address. Pls add all new info including testing and results on the question, not comments.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes I have double checked everything, I have followed the instructions exactly but still the same issue. I have added new info in the question. Thank you for the response

Comment: @Peregrino69 I used sudo netstat -tulpn. Does that mean vncserver is listening to port 5900?

Comment: You actually have 2 running: vncserver-X11 listening on port 5900, TigerVNC Server port 5901. If you're tunneling through SSH, the client's trying to connect to port 9901 which only SSHD is listening to. In a home network I'd start by verifying that VNC works in the first place without SSH. If that works, start figuring out the SSH tunneling :-) I'd also shut down the one VNC server I didn't want to use just to not muddy the waters anymore than I have to.

Comment: @Peregrino69 So I tried connecting without SSH. I added new info in the question. Is that what you mean by trying without SSH? :)

Comment: @Peregrino69 It works!!!! I think I figured it out

Comment: Excellent :-D Don't hesitate to [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) then :-) Please check [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for advice. Basically just write the details of the solution down in the way that would have helped you to resolve the issue yourself, including what the issue in your original attempt is, maybe step-by-step on how you resolved it... Also don't forget to check back after 48 hours to accept your answer.